# What value do I set for the decay parameter of any optimizer in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training an image classification model using transfer learning in Keras. I am using the Adam optimizer with the initial learning rate as 0.001. I want to understand what value do I set for the `decay` parameter. I am training for 100 epochs and using a batch size of 16.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to instantiate `Adam` and set the parameters in the constructor (`__init__`):

```
opt = Adam(lr=0.01, decay=0.99)
model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=opt)
```

The actual value of the parameter is something you have to experiment with, it a hyper-parameter that can be tuned using Grid or Random Search. Some common values are 0.99 and 0.95.

Comment: I am aware of that. I actually meant what would be an appropriate/recommended value for the decay parameter. I guess I did not make that clear in the question. I have edited it

Comment: Does it depend on the number of epochs?